# How to create docker bridge network without internet access?

Tags: docker, containers, bridge

I want to create docker bridge network where I can place containers without internet access but access to each other. How would i go about configuring this?

Comment: Bridge network is meant for a single host, so the internet is not a prerequisite to have one. You might need internet if your containers are pulling or pushing stuff from the internet (even a simple apt-get install requires internet for obvious reasons). On the other hand overlay network is for multiple hosts and might require internet

Answer (score 0):

Sounds like you're looking for the `--internal` option.

From [the docs](https://docs.docker.com/engine/reference/commandline/network_create/#options):

> --internal        Restrict external access to the network